# Converting pyspark DataFrame with date column to Pandas results in AttributeError

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame (pyspark) -

```
 |-- DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A: double (nullable = true)
 |-- B: double (nullable = true)
```

While trying to convert the data frame to `pandas` -

```
res2 = res.toPandas()
```

I got the following error - `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Detailed error -

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-471067d510fa> in <module>
----> 1 res2 = res.toPandas()

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2123                         table = pyarrow.Table.from_batches(batches)
   2124                         pdf = table.to_pandas()
-> 2125                         pdf = _check_dataframe_convert_date(pdf, self.schema)
   2126                         return _check_dataframe_localize_timestamps(pdf, timezone)
   2127                     else:

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in _check_dataframe_convert_date(pdf, schema)
   1705     """
   1706     for field in schema:
-> 1707         pdf[field.name] = _check_series_convert_date(pdf[field.name], field.dataType)
   1708     return pdf
   1709 

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py in _check_series_convert_date(series, data_type)
   1690     """
   1691     if type(data_type) == DateType:
-> 1692         return series.dt.date
   1693     else:
   1694         return series

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5061         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   5062                 name in self._accessors):
-> 5063             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5064         else:
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py in __get__(self, obj, cls)
    169             # we're accessing the attribute of the class, i.e., Dataset.geo
    170             return self._accessor
--> 171         accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
    172         # Replace the property with the accessor object. Inspired by:
    173         # http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py in __new__(cls, data)
    322             pass  # we raise an attribute error anyway
    323 
--> 324         raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike "
    325                              "values")

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Any way to fix it? maybe convert something in the original datafrme?

Comment: Can you print the output of `res.show()`?

Comment: @cs95 added the output to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, can't see exactly what the issue could be. Perhaps you could try converting your date column to timestamp, then trying again: `from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp; res2 = res.withColumn('DATE', to_timestamp(res.DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')).toPandas()`

Comment: @cs95 it worked! thanks! (I could accept that as an answer).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a workaround, you may consider converting your `date` column to `timestamp` (this is more aligned with pandas' `datetime` type).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
res2 = res.withColumn('DATE', to_timestamp(res.DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 3):

I just tested the recommendation by @cs95, which does work. However, in the output of toPandas, I still see the hour:minute:seconds output, like

```
|2017-02-15 00:00:00|
```

Because Pandas takes the date value and fills in times, even though we don't want them. Hence, the format in `to_timestamp` is not helpful.

I get same result with somewhat simpler code:

```
col_name = "DATE"
res.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast("timestamp"))
```

Here's why this is more workable.  In the use case I confront, there are many (many!) columns in the Spark DataFrame and I need to find all of one type and convert to another.  For example, `toPandas` complains about Spark Decimal variables and recommends conversion.  I don't want to run that
one variable at a time.

Here's a function.  I have defaults set for the decimal case, but this approach works for any types to convert.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def spark_type_converter(sdf, x="decimal", y="float"):
    """This uses Spark cast to convert variables of type `x` to `y`.
    :param sdf: Spark data frame
    :param x: character string for input type to cast FROM. 
        This is matched against `dtype` with `startswith`, 
        so only first few characters matter.
    :param y: character string for name of type to cast INTO.
    """
    target_cols = [i for i,j in sdf.dtypes if j.startswith(x)]
    for col_name in target_cols:
        sdf = sdf.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast(y)) 
    return sdf
```

Use in this case, to find all `date` variables and change to `timestamp`:

```
res = spark_type_convert(res, x="date", y="timestamp")
```

When `toPandas` runs, this "one size fits all" approach gives same result.