# pyspark to pandas dataframe: datetime compatability

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am using pyspark to do most of the data wrangling but at the end I need to convert to pandas dataframe. When converting columns that I have formatted to date become "object" dtype in pandas.

Are datetimes between pyspark and pandas incompatible? How can I keep dateformat after pyspark -> pandas dataframe convertion ?

EDIT: [converting to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131202/converting-pyspark-dataframe-with-date-column-to-pandas-results-in-attributeerro) is a workaround as suggested in other question. How can I find out more on data type compatability between pyspark vs pandas ? There is not much info on [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/pandas/pyspark-pandas-conversion.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/pandas_on_spark/types.html#type-casting-between-pandas-and-pandas-api-on-spark), it is more informative than the databricks documentation you linked in the question.

I think the cleanest solution is to use `timestamp` rather than `date` type in your spark code as you said.

The other way to do it (which I wouldn't recommend) would be to convert from `object` back to `datetime` in the pandas dataframe using the [pandas `to_datetime` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Something like this

```
> object_series = pd.Series(["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"])

> df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':object_series})

> df.dtypes 
dates    object
dtype: object

> df = df.assign(dates_2=pd.to_datetime(df.dates))

> df.dtypes 
dates              object
dates_2    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

> df 
        dates    dates_2
0  2022-01-01 2022-01-01
1  2022-01-02 2022-01-02
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. That's what I was looking for to watch out for future